# iOS Geographical Region Monitoring Latitude only

Tags: ios, geolocation

I am trying to understand how I could use the iOS Geographical Regional Monitoring to alert an app if the device crosses a particular latitude. I am not so bothered about the Longitude, as the need is to change a setting based on latitude only.

How can I best achieve this?

Alternatively, if the above is not possible, could I create a rectangular boundary, that say encompassed from x latitude to y latitude, and a longitude to b longitude? Again, if so, how?

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to do that. Why do you need to do something like that?

Comment: Hi. Basically, for an Aurora App I have, I am interested in setting the alert threshold based on the latitude of the user. So, if the user is between a & b latitude, the alert threshold is 1, but if between b & c it is 2, and if between c & d it is 3 etc.

Comment: I think the closest you can get is by using more than one non-overlapping spherical regions for each level to cover to entire longitude range. There isn't any way to monitor a rectangular region in the Location API

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I must say, that was the impression I got from the docs, but hoped I was missing something! It just makes it more of a pain, as to get a nice break point along a latitude would require smallish regions! I will have a think! Thanks again.